# Kotlin - Using data class with type from an interface

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I have an `overrides` interface which I created in order to combine 2 data classes - like so:

```
interface Overrides

data class SoOverrides(
    val soId: String,
    val freeInterval: String?
) : Overrides

data class CoOverrides(
    val coId: String,
    val pubType: String,
) : Overrides
```

I'm then trying to set the type of an item in my main data class to `Overrides` like so:

```
@Document(collection = Campaign.COLLECTION)
data class Campaign(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val overrides: List<Overrides>? = null
) {
    companion object {
        const val COLLECTION: String = "campaigns"
    }
}
```

However whenever I go to run this, I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [co.....models.Overrides]: Specified class is an interface
```

Could someone please explain what I need to do to use that type `Overrides`. I'm extending the interface that way so I can have multiple classes, under one name, but not sure why it doesnt work?

I guess I could just use `val overrides: List<*>? = null`

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the Spring library require the types to instantiable classes (say, for purpose of serialization)?

Comment: can you please add the stacktrace add structure of the document saved in MongoDB, assuming the error occurs on read. Or point us to a gist to run, reproducing the error.